# MySql Select Case to select datafrom tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from one of the tables in the database, on the basis of the parameter.
Here's what I did.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `myDB`.`Temp`(
    IN ID INT(11)
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN ID IN(1,2) THEN
                SELECT * FROM table1;
            WHEN ID IN(3,4) THEN
                SELECT * FROM table2;
        END CASE;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But. I'm getting error:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'SELECT * FROM table1;
        WHEN ID IN(3,4) THEN
            SELECT * FROM table2;
    END' at line 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use subquery inside case when you can use if else clauses.

```
IF(ID IN(1,2)) THEN
        SELECT * FROM table1;
ELSEIF(ID IN(3,4)) THEN
        SELECT * FROM table2;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where id in (1,2)
union all
select * from table2 where id in (3,4)
```

although the column count has to the same across both tables for this to work (and in any case it is not at all bad practice to name the columns in the SELECT to avoid confusion, bahaviour-creep and so on).